# How to put JavaScript DOM elements in object and access them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to place all of JavaScript DOM element queries in an object and access them throughout my script. Here's the current design pattern I'm using and I would like to stick to this format if possible:

```
(function ($) {

EXAMPLE = {

    basicExample : function () {

        config : {
            logo : $('#logo'),
            footer : $('footer'),
        },

        EXAMPLE.config.logo.hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('example');
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('example');
        });
}

EXAMPLE.basicExample();

})(jQuery);
```

Accessing the logo DOM element doesn't seem to work like this: `EXAMPLE.config.logo`

Comment: `config` isn't a property of `EXAMPLE`. It's not even a property or variable of `basicExample` - it's a label (you used `:` instead of `=`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did misplace the `config` part - not in your `EXAMPLE` object literal, but inside your `basicExample` function (where it acted as a [labelled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) block statement with no-op expression statements inside, so it threw no error). Instead, it should be

```
(function ($) {
    EXAMPLE = {
        config : {
            logo : $('#logo'),
            footer : $('footer'),
        },
        basicExample : function () {
            EXAMPLE.config.logo.hover(function () {
                $(this).addClass('example');
            }, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('example');
            });
        }
    };
    EXAMPLE.basicExample();
})(jQuery);
```

However, you will need to place the initialisation into a DOM-ready handler, otherwise it might not find the elements. So either use

```
EXAMPLE = {
    init : function($) {
        EXAMPLE.config = {
            logo : $('#logo'),
            footer : $('footer'),
        };
        EXAMPLE.basicExample();
    },
    basicExample : function() {
        this.config.logo.hover(function () {
            jQuery(this).addClass('example');
        }, function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('example');
        });
    }
};
jQuery(EXAMPLE.init);
```

or just put everything in the handler, without any module pattern and extra `basicExample` function:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var config = {
        logo : $('#logo'),
        footer : $('footer'),
    };
    config.logo.hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('example');
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('example');
    });
});
```

Comment: could also work, just not sure if that's what he ment, or was just using EXAMPLE as a namespace..one or the other ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are using object literal notation to define an object, and inside that object you define a constructor function, that needs to be used via new to be useful..I believe what you wanted is to create a namespace with a single object inside it.

try to remove the function and you should be able to access it, hence:

```
var EXAMPLE = {
   basicExample : {
     config : {
         logo : $('#logo')
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest declare a global object like this:

```
EXAMPLE = {
    basicExample: function () {
        this.config = {
            logo: $('#logo'),
            footer: $('footer')
        };
        return this;
    },
    applyHover: function () {
        this.config.logo.hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('example');
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('example');
        });
    }
};
```

And then call a `.basicExample().applyHover()` on document ready.
**[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HYfUv/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma at the end of the `config`.

```
config : {
            logo : $('#logo'),
            footer : $('footer'),
        },
```

Should be:

```
config : {
            logo : $('#logo'),
            footer : $('footer')
        },
```

Comment: Since the official death of IE7, extra comma shouldn't be a problem anymore

Comment: @roasted Sorry, no official death of IE7

Comment: IE7 ships with windows XP, it will never die! though this answer should have probably been a comment, but he doesn't have the rep (yet).

Comment: @roasted Yeah seriously...I'm tired of "having to support it"

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
var EXAMPLE = {
   basicExample : {
     config : {
         logo : $('#logo')
     }
  }
}
EXAMPLE.basicExample.config.logo.hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('example');
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('example');
        });
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VJFW5/1/)

Or you can do what [Artyom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16676482/573634) suggested.

Comment: Why not use the `hover` method like OP did?

Answer (score -2):

`EXAMPLE.basicExample` is a function this is wrapping your `config` parameter. That is why it is not available to `EXAMPLE.config`. If you want the function `EXAMPLE.basicEXAMPLE` to define `config` as an element of `EXAMPLE` then do this:

```
EXAMPLE = {

    basicExample : function () {

        EXAMPLE.config = {
            logo : $('#logo'),
            footer : $('footer'),
        },

        EXAMPLE.config.logo.hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('example');
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('example');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I even tested this and it works and answers the question.

Comment: No, it does not work. It still has the same mistake (not my downvote, though).

Comment: Yeah, I tested this as well and it does not work (also not my downvote)

Comment: Ok it was a typo missing `=` in place of the `:`. But the key was that it declares `EXAMPLE.config` instead of `config`. And it works.